# Retrieve current lat/long from iphone without displaying a map

Tags: objective-c

I need to acquire the current lat/long from the iphone without displaying a map.

Can this be accomplished??

objective C please.

thank you
tony

Answer (score 1):

Look at `CLLocationManager`. You can simply create an instance, setting your controller as delegate, start the instance to acquire your location, and in your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate methods to handle the results, you can access the coordinates. No map required.

Comment: Hi Mark....  Thanks for the quick reply.....   do you have a code sample that i can see??   thank you

Comment: Actually, @bensnider's example is all you need. You'd put that code in your app delegate. In `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` you'd call `[self startUpdates]`. You'll have to fill in the details of `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation`, but essentially the information you are looking for is in the `newLocation` argument of that delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)startUpdates {
    coreManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    coreManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    coreManager.delegate = self;
    [coreManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // newLocation is location from gps...
    // you'll need to stop coreManager updating when you have a good fix
}
```

See the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) for details.

Comment: definately, all you need is whats in 'newLocation'

Comment: Thanks for the code block...   where would i place this code block??

Answer (score 1):

CLLocationManager is the interface you must use in order to retrieve current Lat/Long

Below is the code:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
locationManager.distanceFilter = DISTANCE_FILTER_VALUE;
locationManager.delegate = self; 
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) for it.